# Convert a Variable into Observable Stream

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a use case where the width of a particular div changes w.r.t dom and i am using view child to tap on to the width .

I want to only use the latest width value where as Angular gives intermediate Results too . How can i convert a variable into a Observable Stream . I tried using Observable.of but it only subscribes to it once and not after that .

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[watchValueChange]'
})
export class ChangeDirective{

  @Output() onValueChange = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Input('watchValueChange') public valueChange: any = null;
```

> // this value receives the width dynamically i want to make this an
>   Observable so that i can subscribe and use debouce to get only the
>   values after all changes are done but after the first subscribe when
>   the input changes it doesnt work

```
  private changeEvent: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.valueChange.asObservable().debounceTime(300).subscribe(value => {
      this.onValueChange.emit(value);
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes){
    this.changeEvent.next(this.valueChange);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're looking for [`auditTime`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-auditTime) instead.

```
this.changeEvent.auditTime(300).subscribe(value => {
    this.onValueChange.emit(value);
});
```

I don't know what you mean by:

> ...after the first subscribe when the input changes it doesnt work

Maybe you want to use `ReplaySubject(1)` instead of `Subject()`?

Comment: actually i want to tap on the valurChange and not the changeEvent how to do that it gives me this error _this.valueChange.auditTime is not a function_

Comment: Did you import the operator with "import 'rxjs/add/operator/auditTime';"?

Comment: the problem here is @martin that the input the valueChange is not a Stream but just a normal integer value how will audit time work in this case